# storage selected listbox items into a new array

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I store the selected item(s) in a `listbox` to a new array? Like we select the items and then do the button's action, e.g.

```
string[] domains = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    domains[i] = listBox1.SelectedIndices[i].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code won't work because index i is not used to indicate `SelectedIndices`, but `Items`.

So update it:

```
string[] domains = new string[listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count];
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count; i++)
{
    domains[i] = listBox.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndices[i]].ToString();
}
```

What I prefer:

```
List<string> domains = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.SelectedIndices.Count; i++)
{
    domains.Add(listBox.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndices[i]].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 6):

What about this:

```
string[] domains = listBox1.SelectedItems.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```